# Cucumber: How to execute the entire list of Scenario Outline along with example for a different set of attributes

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a situation where I need to run the scenario outline along with all the datatable for different set of value. I am looking for an datatable inside another datatable. That I need to run my entire list of examples of a scenario outline repeatedly for the given list of products.

Note: I am trying to avoid write different scenario for each product.

I have given some example and my problem statement for better understanding as below

```
Scenario Outline : Check the behaviour of all the products

Given the POST retrieveProductdetails api url with valid authorization
When POST api is applied for the <"Products">
Then verify the behaviour of all the <"Properties"> and its <"result">

Examples:

|Properties         |result|
|Appearance         | Successful|
|reading            | Successful|
|writing            |Successful|
|memo               |Successful|
|Singing            |Successful|
|Help               |Successful|
|Adancefeature      |Successful|
|Antiquefeatuer     |Succesful|
|AI nature          |Successful|
|Interaction        |Successful|
```

Note : I have around 20 Products to be validated and for each and every product i need validate all the 10 properties as mentioned .

If I start to write a an third Variable like as below , I will end up in writing 200 lines/examples (20 *10 = 200 ). And similar to the above scenario i have around 25 to 30 details which needed to be validate for all 20 products . The maintenance will be very difficult. Is there any better option for this ?

```
Examples:
|Properties         |result         |Products|
|Appearance         | Successful    |Alexa|


List of Products
|Products|
|Alexa|
|firetv|
|GoogleHome|
|Chromecast|
|SmartHub|
|SmartTV|
|AmazonVideo|
|AmazonPhoto|
|Echo|
|Echo Dot|
|Echo Show|
|Ring|
.
.
.
.
|SmartHome|
```

Comment: Anyone faced this situation ? any idea how better we can handle this guys ?

Answer (score 0):

You are making this very difficult on yourself for a couple of reasons.

1. You are not describing the behavior of the system. I'm not sure what your application is supposed to do but it seems that you have a particular type of product and all instances of that type of product should have certain flags set.

   However you didn't write this down, rather you appear to be retrieving all products of that type from a database and checking if these have the right flags set. So I have to infer the behavior of the system from your scenario. This should be the other way around.
2. You are trying to programming in Gherkin. Steps in Gherkin are not steps in a test script. They do not have to describe the exact operation needed to get some result. When you use Gherkin to describe the behavior of a system it shouldn't matter if you talk to the system in a unit tests, via http or a browser.

   However by describing the exact operations you are painting yourself in a corner. It means that you can't effectively generalize without using programming language constructs like loops. If you step away from describing exact operations and rather try to describe what the system does you can use a much bigger vocabulary.
3. You appear to be testing against fixed data. Your data appears to have been put into the system already. You are merely checking if it comes out alright. This is not a good test because it assumes the system is in a particular state rather then creating the system in that state or verifying it is.

So to fix your feature file you might want to something like this:

```
Scenario: All smart home products are in the category of AI powered spy-devices 
  Given the smart home product "<Product>"
  When I inspect this smart home product
  Then it has all the properties of an AI powered spy-device:
    | Appearance         |
    | reading            |
    | writing            |
    | memo               |
    | Singing            |
    | Help               |
    | Adancefeature      |
    | Antiquefeatuer     |
    | AI nature          |
    | Interaction        |
    
  Examples:
    | Product     |
    | Alexa       |
    | firetv      |
    | GoogleHome  | 
    | Chromecast  |
    | SmartHub    |
    | SmartTV     |
    | AmazonVideo |
    | AmazonPhoto |
    | Echo        |
    | Echo Dot    |
    | Echo Show   |
    | Ring        |
    .
    .
    .
    .
    | SmartHome   |
```

While in the `Given` step you'd normally create the product, in your case you'll have to fetch the catalogue of products and verify that the catalogue contains the product. In the `When` step you'd probably fetch the details for the product. Finally in the `Then` step you'd verify if all properties have been set when looking at the details.

edit:

If you actually want to check if all the data has been entered into the system correctly you could also do something like this:

```
Scenario: All smart home products are in the category of AI powered spy-devices 
  Given the smart home product "<Product>"
  When I inspect this smart home product
  Then it has all the properties:
    | Appearance         | <Apperance> |
    | reading            | <Reading>   |
    | writing            | <....>      |
    | memo               |             |
    | Singing            |
    | Help               |
    | Adancefeature      |
    | Antiquefeatuer     |
    | AI nature          |
    | Interaction        |
    
  Examples:
    | Product     | Apperance | Reading | ....
    | Alexa       | Yes       | No
    | firetv      | No        | Yes
    | GoogleHome  | Yes       | No
    .
    .
    .
    .
    | SmartHome   | No        | Yes     | ....
```

But I would suggest not using Cucumber for this. In that case you'd be better of putting your data into an excel file and using JUnit5s parameterized test.